# Python int() of a string that is a float number

Tags: python

In all probability a stupid question, but I was wondering why python can't make a integer out of a string that is actually a float number.

```
>>> int(1.0)
1
>>> int(float('1.0'))
1
```

But

```
>>> int('1.0')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    int('1.0')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.0'
```

Can anyone clarify why it cant be done in one step?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Straight from the docs about `int`:

> If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string or Unicode object representing an integer literal in radix base.

And here is how an integer literal in radix base is defined:

```
longinteger    ::=  integer ("l" | "L")
integer        ::=  decimalinteger | octinteger | hexinteger | bininteger
decimalinteger ::=  nonzerodigit digit* | "0"
octinteger     ::=  "0" ("o" | "O") octdigit+ | "0" octdigit+
hexinteger     ::=  "0" ("x" | "X") hexdigit+
bininteger     ::=  "0" ("b" | "B") bindigit+
nonzerodigit   ::=  "1"..."9"
octdigit       ::=  "0"..."7"
bindigit       ::=  "0" | "1"
hexdigit       ::=  digit | "a"..."f" | "A"..."F"
```

As you can see `.` is not present in the lexical definition.

more on [int](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) and [integer literals](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-and-long-integer-literals)

Also worth mentioning that what you wish is naturally achievable in languages of [static typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_typing), while Python employs [dynamic typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Dynamic_typing)

Comment: You sure this is relevant? You're quoting the rules of Python syntax, which don't correspond exactly to what arguments the `int` function accepts.

Comment: @Kos I'm quoting what an integer literal is. `int` accepts either a number or a string/unicode object that represents an **integer literal**

Comment: As a side note, the [lexical analysis docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html) are an interesting read for people interested in lexers

Answer (score 15):

> Can anyone clarify why it cant be done in one step?

To quote the Zen of Python: [Explicit is better than implicit.](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

> I was wondering why python can't make a integer out of a string that is actually a float number.

In line with Python's philosophy, if a string contains a float number which you then want to turn into an int, it's your responsibility to spell things out. The language won't try and second-guess your intentions.

Comment: I meant in relation to how it's stored in the Memory/Hardware :)

Comment: @TapajitDey: The question has nothing to do with how things are stored in memory/hardware. The choice of not allowing implicit conversions of this sort was a deliberate decision by Python's designers.

Comment: @TapajitDey Python is a high-level interpreted language, and how it represents data internally is an implementation detail. Why would you rely on it?

Comment: I guess that's true, but it just felt kind of limiting