# How to explain the int() function to a beginner

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am tutoring a neighbour's child and we were exploring the `int()` function before using it with input()  - which returns a string. We tried the following:

```
int(5)
int(5.5)
int('5')
int('5.5')
```

The first three returned `5` as expected; the last one threw the error

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5.5'

Given the behaviour of the first three lines how do I explain the error to a 14-year old (background = speaks 4 languages but maths is not so hot)?

**UPDATE**
C# exhibits the same behaviour:
`Convert.ToInt32("5.5");` throws the error

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: It can only take strings that are how you'd write *whole* numbers?

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15132352/python-int-of-a-string-that-is-a-float-number

Comment: This would be a good question for [CS.ComputerScienceEducators](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Nat Done, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Btw: `Convert.ToInt32("5.5");` - depends on your PC locale settings. Some nations use `.` as delimeter, so your convert will be ok but `5,5` will throw exception. Actually, you can set delimeter to whatewer you want in windows settings (want to use `5€5`? Why not? :D )

Comment: @Jan *"Why not?"* – Because ಠ_ಠ

Comment: note: `int('0١۲߃४৫੬૭୮௯')` is  `123456789`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In a nutshell: *because that's what the spec says.* That's kind of a useful mindset to get into anyway. ;-)

Now, why does the spec say so? There are only a finite number of types a function can accept as valid input. The `int` function tries to cover two different kinds of use cases:

1. convert a string representation of an integer into an actual `int`
2. cast a `float` value to an `int`, truncating it*

The third use case, *"convert the string representation of a floating point number to an `int`"* is not covered by the spec, because the language designers decided not to cover it. Which seems like a reasonable decision to make, since they needed to draw the line somewhere on what types the function would and wouldn't accept. The string representation of a floating point number should be parsed by `float`, not `int`.

** Actually: any object that has an `__int__` method, but lets keep it simple.*

---

As a counter example, in PHP you *can* try to cast any string to an `int`, and it will try to give you the best match:

```
php > echo (int)'3.14';
3
php > echo (float)'3.14';
3.14
php > echo (int)'3 little pigs';
3
php > echo (int)'there are 3 little pigs';
0
```

Which, quite honestly, is rather insane behaviour, especially that last one. Python has a strict(er) type system; if you're trying to parse a string as an `int`, it must be a perfectly valid representation of an integer number, not merely something that somewhere contains something that can be interpreted as a number.

Comment: also a good answer, int() does only 1 thing. String to int or float to int, but not string to float to int. I was more trying to answer it the "children" way, maybe more for like an 8 year old rather than 14. - nice challenge

Comment: @EvilSmurf Under the hood in CPython implementation is `int()` actually doing 1 thing rather than 2?

Comment: I guess we'd really need one of the Python core devs to tell us why `int()` behaves this way. But the way I see it is that Python is being helpful in raising ValueError on `int(some_string)` when `some_string` is a string that doesn't represent an integer, since it will often be used to convert user input. And as every good programmer should know you can't trust users to give you valid input. ;) But `int(some_float)` will almost always be called on a valid floating-point number, so that conversion is almost always safe to perform, unless of course `some_float` happens to be `nan` or `±inf`.

Comment: @PM2Ring The other way around… how *do* you convert a `float` to an `int` if not by using `int()`?

Comment: Good point. I guess `float` _could_ have a `.to_int` method, but it doesn't for historical reasons. And it makes sense to have a generic `int` type that invokes the `__int__` method of classes that define such a method, since that's consistent with other "magic" methods like `__len__`.

Comment: @deceze by calling `floor()` and `ceil()` from the `math` package and doing exactly what you want to do. casting `float` to `int` loses information, and in a way, you *should* tell your program how you want to lose it.

Comment: @Arne Arguably casting a `float` to an `int` is a pretty common operation and should not require a separate module to be imported. In many C-like languages it's the built-in operation `(int)f`. The operation is also well defined: truncate towards zero. If you do need more specific behaviour, importing `math` is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @deceze Eh, as soon as words like *should* get involved it boils down to which one of the python zens you think applies most in this situation. The pyhton devs apparently thought `practicality beats purity` and honestly that's good enough for me.

Comment: @PM2Ring: If the goal is to get the whole-number part of a string, starting out by converting it to "float" could result in a loss of precision, could it not?

Comment: @supercat If the goal is to extract a substring, you should probably be looking at `re`.

Comment: the last two (`there are 3 little pigs` -> 0 and `3 little pigs` -> 3) seem to be what the C library functions (`atoi()` and `strtol()`) do, they parse a number and ignore the rest. (`strtol()` gives you the pointer to the trailing part of the string, which you can use to check if the string contained more than the number.)

Comment: @ilkkachu Which is fine if that's what you want to do and you're explicitly calling those functions; it seems like crazy default behaviour for `(int)` though.

Comment: Another PHP WTF: say $x is "5d8". After running $x++ you get "5d9". OK, that's pretty crazy, but not totally crazy yet. Increment again, you'll get "5e0". OK, that's pretty strange. But the best is yet to come. Increment once again, and you get... 6. "5e0" is interpreted as 5*10^0...

Comment: @Muzer Nice illustration for why *limiting* the number of acceptable values is preferable to trying to work with *everything* - at some point the behaviour becomes somewhere between unpredictable, undefined and nonsensical.

Comment: For a great illustration as to why it is not a good idea to be too accepting in type conversions: https://blog.checkpoint.com/2016/02/02/ebay-platform-exposed-to-severe-vulnerability/. Javascript lets you write code using 6 characters, `[`, `]`, `{`, `}`, `+` and `!`, everything else flows from type conversions.

Comment: @Martijn Soooo… Javascript is really just Brainfuck with some added syntactic sugar?

Comment: @deceze: Javascript is really just Brainfuck with some readability extensions. But those are totally optional and only used by wimps.

Answer (score 30):

The problem with that line is that there are two conversions involved:

```
"5.5" (string) -> 5.5 (float) -> 5 (int)
```

The conversion operators in Python will only apply one conversion at a time, never two chained, because that could become confusing in many cases.

The solution is to apply two nested conversions:

```
int(float("5.5"))
```

Comment: This isn't what the OPs asking though?

Comment: While this is absolutely the correct answer, I don't know if it is very useful to a child.

Comment: @JonClements: Well, yes. The OP asks why the last line is different, and that is because it contains two conversions while the other lines contain just one. That's the perfectly reasonable reason...

Comment: Not sure it quite addresses the question which is "How do I explain the last line to a 14 year old"?

Comment: @JonClements: That would depend on the child and their background. For my 14 year old myself, saying: "you are writing one conversion but you expect to get two" should have been enough, I think.

Comment: @JonClements: OTOH, once I failed to explain to a 18 year old why `"5" == int` (in C!) would not work... people are not compilers, some will understand, some will not...

Comment: The 1 vs. 2 conversions, does this make sense from the way `int()` is implemented in CPython?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Maybe that is the design philosophy, because technically it is not really necessary. From a technical POV, `int()` is just an overloaded function, and reacts differently depending on the input-argument type. In case of a float, it floors the result. In case of a string, it doesn't.

Comment: I don't think it actually answers the question. Basically leaves OP with another question: "why it requires two conversions?" Try `parseInt("5.5")` in JavaScript or `atoi("5.5")` in C, or `int("5.5")` in Perl or ...

Comment: @el.pescado: Ah, but that is easy: it requires two conversions because `"5.5"` is not the string representation of a valid `int`, but it _is_ of a valid `float`. The fact that other languages will happily do that is, IMHO, a sign of the good design of Python (try `atoi("5asdf")` in C or `int("5qwer")` in Perl and try to explain that to the 14 year old...). And about the JavaScript case, I barely understand it myself!

Comment: @rodrigo But why you need `float` when you're interested in `int`?

Comment: @rodrigo: Why "5.5" is not string representation of valid int whereas `5.5` *is* float representation of valid int?

Comment: @el.pescado: Because a string is converted to integer by parsing it, and `"5.5"` has a decimal dot, so it is invalid format; while a float is converted to integer by truncating it, so it is correct. You could argue that when parsing a string it should ignore unknown trailing characters, as C/Perl does, but that is not the Python way (_"explicit is better than implicit"_).

Comment: @rodrigo "...except one implicit coersion is ok"

Answer (score 5):

You could refer to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

> ```
> class int(x=0)
> class int(x, base=10)
> ```
>
> Return an integer object constructed from a number or string x, or return 0 if no arguments are given. If x is a number, return
>   `x.__int__()`. **For floating point numbers, this truncates towards zero**.
>
> **If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string, bytes, or bytearray instance representing an *integer* literal in radix
>   base.** Optionally, the literal can be preceded by + or - (with no space
>   in between) and surrounded by whitespace. A base-n literal consists of
>   the digits 0 to n-1, with a to z (or A to Z) having values 10 to 35.
>   The default base is 10. The allowed values are 0 and 2–36. Base-2, -8,
>   and -16 literals can be optionally prefixed with 0b/0B, 0o/0O, or
>   0x/0X, as with integer literals in code. Base 0 means to interpret
>   exactly as a code literal, so that the actual base is 2, 8, 10, or 16,
>   and so that int('010', 0) is not legal, while int('010') is, as well
>   as int('010', 8).
>
> The integer type is described in Numeric Types — int, float, complex.

(emphasis mine)

Referring to docs teaches that in programming nothing is really arbitrary, and compilers/interpreters are simply following rules.

Answer (score 3):

I think I would go about it by saying that both `int(5.5)` and `int('5.5')` are not what you are Supposed To Do. rodrigo's answer gives an explanation why one still works, but when explaining things to a child I would try to keep things as explicit as possible, and implicit conversions don't help with that.

So, while overly explicit, why not teach to go like this:

`int(floor(float('5.5')))`

At least then everything is perfectly clear and obvious.

Comment: why is the call to `floor()` required here?

Comment: @shea It isn't, it just makes the part where 5.5 gets rounded to 5 explicit. It's from the `math` package btw.

Comment: wouldn't it be a clearer demonstration of how `int` works if it was just `int(float('5.5'))`?

Comment: In the sense of how python works, I guess so. Then again, I personally would have been glad if the language was a bit more explicit in what it does when I picked it up, so it boils down to how the kid in question learns it best. I wanted to offer this 'be as explicit as possible' perspective.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the problem behind this is **operator overloading**, because there are really two int() functions involved: one that converts a string (if possible), the other truncates floats. If the kid understands types, I think she/he will also understand what overloading is.

Answer (score 1):

Try explaining strings containing digits as if it was written out as words.

```
int(5)
int(5.5)
```

works since Python's int() function "sees" it as numbers and takes the whole-number-part, like another child, that doesn't know anything about floating point / decimal places -> both would be interpreted as 5, the rest is ignored.

Now: using strings

```
int('5')
int('5.5')
```

could be interpreted as either "five" which Python's int() function knows how to translate to 5, but a verbal "fivepointfive" is not what our child has ever heard, not knowing anything about floating point. (int() function being the child here)

A nice question and an usual challenge to try explain it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Your (imaginary) function takes a picture of a cat as a parameter and you tried to pass it an actual cat. There's a conversion that needs to happen first from cat to picture of cat before the function knows what to do with it.